# May I know how do i change the out of stock message in front of my store page, I use the Astra Theme I want to change it to sold out

Tags: customization

[image]

I am currently trying to change the out of stock line on my website to SOLD OUT, currently using astra and cant find a way to change it

Comment: https://wpastra.com/docs/change-woocommerce-out-of-stock-text/